# Сложная таблица связь один-ко-многим как организовать(MySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql

Привет всем! Я, честно говоря, уже весьма запутался ища ответ на свой вопрос, может быть кто-то сможет доступно объяснить и показать на примере то что требуется.

Итак, собственно проблема: из гугления я понял, что для меня требуется создать две таблицы со связью один-ко-многим. Есть таблица тремя полями: 1) id записи; 2) заголовок (title); 3) ссылка на файл (url). Особенность в том, что пользователь приходит на страницу по ссылке вида домен/имяскрипта.php?переменная=12345(комбинация цифр). Создается множество комбинаций цифр и вот как теперь связать одну запись из первой таблицы и множество комбинаций? Как должна выглядеть вторая таблица?

Т.е. страница генерируется на основе комбинации цифр, а после просмотра данная комбинация должна быть удалена. Что бы пользователь не смог второй раз воспользоваться данной ему ссылкой. Второй пользователь может попасть на эту же страницу, но только по другой комбинации. Простите, что так сумбурно описываю, я не совсем понимаю как объяснить.

Comment: так вы же все рассказали. в чем у вас проблема? что не работает?

Comment: @splash58 на данный момент у меня есть только одна таблица. Я не пойму как должна выглядеть вторая таблица и как их связать

Comment: пишите во вторую таблицу кодовую комбинацию и id. когда обращение происходит к файлу, удаляйте строку

Comment: @splash58 проблема в том, что комбинаций может быть 100, может 10, была бы одна тогда была бы одна таблица и четыре поля

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можете сделать примерно так, как приведено ниже.

связь таблиц, осуществляемая конструкцией `foreign key` (внешний ключ) желательно, но не необходима.

в первом запросе выводятся данные для существующего кода (`123`), второй запрос возвращает пустой набор, т.к. искомого кода (`555`) в таблице кодов — нет.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a51b/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table urly (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  title text,
  url text
);

create table cody (
  cid int,
  code int,
  foreign key (cid) references urly (id)
);

insert into urly (title, url) values
  ('заголовок1', 'http://url1'),
  ('заголовок2', 'http://url2');

insert into cody values
  (1, 123),
  (2, 456),
  (1, 789);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select urly.title, urly.url
from urly
join cody
  on urly.id = cody.cid
where cody.code = 123
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a51b/2/0)**:

```
|      title |         url |
|------------|-------------|
| заголовок1 | http://url1 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select urly.title, urly.url
from urly
join cody
  on urly.id = cody.cid
where cody.code = 555
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a51b/2/1)**:

```
|      title |         url |
|------------|-------------|
```

Comment: сколько добавите строк в таблицу `cody`, столько и будет.

Comment: Честно говоря не совсем понял. Но только когда есть одна комбинация цифр, тогда все просто вроде. Но я хочу использовать до сотни комбинаций. Т.е. первая запись в первой таблице выглядит так: id, title, url, соотвественно 1, тест, домен/папка/файл. И вот к этой записи должна быть привязано сотня комбинаций, например 123, 1234, 12345.  Дальше это должно выглядеть так: пользователь заходит на страницу домен/имяскрипта.php?переменная=123, ему отдается контент из первой таблицы, а из второй удаляется только комбинация 123, 1234 и 12345 остаются  все еще привязаны к записи из первой таблицы

Comment: @Anykey, вот и делайте так, как описали. в чём вы видите сложности?

Comment: Стыдно признаваться, для меня это сложно воплотить в код, но кажется я уловил суть и сейчас буду пробовать реализовать

Comment: @Anykey, не знаете, как удаляются строки из таблицы? например. так: `delete from cody where code=123;`

Comment: подскажите еще, пожалуйста. Как должен выглядеть запрос на создание новой записи? 'INSERT INTO urly (id, title, url) VALUES (NULL, '{$переменная1}', '{$переменная2}')"' это на первую таблицу urly, а как дописать во вторую и объединить с первой? Во вторую надо дописать переменную3 и объединить эту запись с только что добавленной

Comment: @Anykey, даже в самом же ответе есть пример одной из возможных форм оператора `insert`. другие формы можно посмотреть в [соответствующей документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html).

Comment: @Anykey, сейчас только увидел, что вы дополнили свой комментарий. я думаю, вам имеет смысл задать новый вопрос по этому поводу.